# Delete part of word right/left to the cursor in vim

Tags: vim

Let cursor is positioned on some inner symbol of word in vim. I'd like to delete part of word from the left (or right) of cursor. How it can be done (in normal and insert mode)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`db` deletes from the cursor to the beginning of the current word.

`de` deletes from the cursor to the end of the current word.

Comment: Thank you (+1). Is there a way to do the same in insert mode?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I wouldn't know.  Sorry.

Comment: Just to expand on the answer this is the standard "command + motion" vim syntax so "d/foo" would erase everthing up until the string "foo" is found (similarly "d?foo" for backward motion)

Comment: @Loom insert mode is called "insert", because in this mode, your main task should be inserting text. Normal mode is called normal mode because it is the mode you should normally stay with.  So the answer to your comment: go back to normal mode. If you have to do it in Insert mode, you can press `ctrl-o` then `db`

Comment: You also can use cb and ce instead of db and de in normal mode. These commands do the same, but switch current mode into insert mode.

Comment: @Loom in insert mode try ctrl-w to cut up to beginning of the word from cursor